# Full Screen Gallery View on User Click

Tags: android

I use a Gallery view to display set of images in the header part of my application's main page. Now I need to make the Gallery full screen when user click on any gallery image. In the full screen mode it should have the Gallery functionality (Should be able to move between images...). Finally, in the full screen mode, when user click the image, it should go  back to normal screen.
It this possible with Android? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you haven't told us what you've tried or haven't and thus it's hard to pick a starting point...

How I would do it, might be a little over kill using an added activity but I prefer the organization, but launch a new activity on view click and pass the strings of the paths in a bundle and the index of the one selected. Then create a bitmap or imageview, however you want to do it but make sure it can have a setOnTouchListener. This way you can use the MotionEvent to see if they swiped left or right and navigate through the list of images you passed to the activity as strings.

If you don't feel like doing bundles, you can make a static class that holds all the image information..

Comment: Hi SMASH, Thanks for your answer. I'll try it this way and let you know the result. Thanks.